# How to get images over img referrer policy?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

is there any way to hide all images, that use referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"?
I know how to get images by class or id. But I didnt find referrerpolicy.

I would like to add a class to all images on a page having referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" in it.

```
<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src='...'>
```

And after:

```
<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" class='hidden' src='...'>
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Just use a css selector:  document.querySelectorAll("img[referrerpolicy=unsafe-url]").forEach(img => img.classList.add("myclass") )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that but in your browser, I tested it in chrome, firefox, it's ok. Here in snippet not.

```css
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(el=> {
  if (el.referrerPolicy==='unsafe-url') {
    el.style.display='none';
  }
}

)
```

```html
<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600'>
<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600'>
<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600'>
<img referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600'>
```